# Remove IP addresses from a String in Java

Tags: java, string

Is there any way that you can remove IPs from a string?

The input file we get sometimes has IPs attached to the user name, e.g.

```
Jan vd Merwe
Piet Breedt (172.166.23.41)
Jan vd Merwe (164.23.23.51)
Sarel Fourie (23.12.167.244)
Piet Breedt
```

So if there is an IP, I want to remove it. I have been looking at alot of functions but cant seem to get the indexing and parameters right.

Comment: Do you like to *extract* the ip? (Or remove it and extract the name)

Comment: Do you want to remove it `in` the file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use String.replace():

```
String myString = "Piet Breedt (172.166.23.41)";
// replace everything in between the parens (including the parens) by the empty String
myString = myString.replace("\(.*\)", "");
```

Of course, the regex could be specialised to only match ips, something like

```
\(\\d{1,3}\.\\d{1,3}\.\\d{1,3}.\\d{1,3}\)
```

**EDIT**

Here's how you would replace the lines in the files (pseudocode):

1. Open the original file. Open a temporary file.
2. Read line by line. This will give you a String for every line.
3. Remove the contents within the String. Write the new String to the temporary file.
4. When done, replace the original file by the temporary file.

Comment: regular expression should be \\(\\d{1,3}\.\\d{1,3}\.\\d{1,3}.\\d{1,3}\\)

Comment: how would i use it without the array, ie what would i need to change.

Answer (score 2):

You could look for the `(` and remove the remaining string.

```
public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        String[] names = { "Jan vd Merwe", 
                           "Piet Breedt (172.166.23.41)",
                           "Jan vd Merwe (164.23.23.51)", 
                           "Sarel Fourie (23.12.167.244)" };

        for (String name : names) {

            int parIndex = name.indexLastOf('(');
            if (parIndex != -1)
                name = name.substring(0, parIndex-1);

            System.out.println(name);
        }
    }
}
```

prints:

```
Jan vd Merwe
Piet Breedt
Jan vd Merwe
Sarel Fourie
```

---

Another solution, based on regular expressions:

```
    String[] names = { "Jan vd Merwe", 
                       "Piet Breedt (172.166.23.41)",
                       "Jan vd Merwe (164.23.23.51)", 
                       "Sarel Fourie (23.12.167.244)" };

    String ipExp = "\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}\\.\\d{1,3}";
    Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("(.*?)\\s*(\\(" + ipExp + "\\))?");

    for (String nameIp : names) {
        Matcher m = pattern.matcher(nameIp);
        if (m.matches()) {
            String name = m.group(1);
            String ip = m.group(2) == null ? "n/a" : m.group(2);
            System.out.printf("Name: %s, Ip: %s%n", name, ip);
        }
    }
```

Prints

```
Name: Jan vd Merwe, Ip: n/a
Name: Piet Breedt, Ip: (172.166.23.41)
Name: Jan vd Merwe, Ip: (164.23.23.51)
Name: Sarel Fourie, Ip: (23.12.167.244)
```

Comment: your first solution will fail for `Jan vd Merwe(Jan)` such data

Comment: That's not in the 'spec'.  It says IPs.  Maybe the OP wants to keep the stuff in the parenthesis if it isn't an IP.

Comment: @org.life.java: That wasn't defined anywhere. No need to worry about special cases if OP is sure there aren't any.

Comment: @org.life.java, changed to *last*IndexOf... :-)